# WPF C# Treeview Scroll to the top of the Treeview

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

When starting my application I have in the form load event to expand the treeview control but it scrolls to bottom of the list.  How do I get the treeview back to the top of the list of nodes.

Comment: adding your code will surely help and understand, what you have done so far. However, try this: `TreeView.Nodes[0].EnsureVisible();`

Comment: here is a snipped of code       private void frmMain_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Treeview1.ExpandAll();
            


            // outputfile = File.AppendText(@"..\video.txt");
            btnPlay.Enabled = false;
            btnPause.Enabled = false;
            btnStop.Enabled = false;
            btnBackward.Enabled = false;
            btnForward.Enabled = false;
            int videoCounter=0,videoCounter1=0;

Comment: That works.  Thank you Muhammad Arslan Jamshad